# Multiple infoWindows stacking over same location Google Maps API version 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm loading a json file for a bunch of markers on my google map (verison 3 api) and then placing infoWindows for each marker.

It all works swimmingly well except that the markers are ignoring the latlng information, and when markers are clicked the windows simply stack over the original marker.

Everything works perfectly except for the positioning and the infoWindows display the correct latlng information so it 'seems' to be correctly received during each iteration of the json file.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    $.each(json.properties, function(i, property) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(property.lat, property.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: markerImage
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div id="balloon"><img src="../images/20010007_1.jpg" class="balloonpic"><strong>' + property.title + '</strong><br />' + latLng + '</div>'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are both lat and lng not working or just one of them? How should the InfoWindow be opend? "stack over the original marker" sounds to me a bit unclear.

Comment: Pretty sure it's both lat and long as the infoWindow opens over the location of the first marker. It's as if infoWindow is keeping the latlong from the first marker and popping each window over that location. I know the windows are different because they have the correct information from the json array each time.